# could not find function "kable_pipe" / "kable_simple"

Tags: kable

I am trying to create a table using
`knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "simple")`
`knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "pipe")`
Although this should work according to https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html,
it just returns `could not find function "kable_pipe"`.

`knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "html")`
and
`knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "latex")`

work perfectly fine.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem as this and figured out the problem is that the default knitr install needs to be updated. I think knitr is installed for Rstudio usage. Maybe it uses an old version?

Anyway solution is to do

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

and then restart R. Should work after that.

Comment: need to get at least knitr 1.33? maybe a few minor versions sooner.