# How can I get around this error using Kable in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I am simply trying to format this table using the Kable function in R Markdown:

```
df <- structure(list(n = 120559L, min = -143.53, q1 = c(`25%` = 0), 
    median = 417.524, mean = 512.838195862607, q3 = c(`75%` = 896.6585), 
    max = 23424.314), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

This code works fine:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

kable(df)
```

But when I try to format the table is gives me an error:

[image]

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825189/could-not-find-function-kable-pipe-kable-simple) but it did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Try with updated package versions.  It is working fine for me

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) the "simple" format relates to "Pandoc’s simple tables" - do you have Pandoc installed? Install guide: https://pandoc.org/installing.html (unfortunately I can't replicate the error to check though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between running the code from the console and knitting your Rmarkdown document. when you render your Rmarkdown file, it loads the libraries and document code, I believe this issue is that you knitted your Rmarkdown document, but didn't run the code in the console to load the libraries into the R session rather than just the document. as both comments suggested, make sure the packages are loaded into the session(and to date) and you should be good to go.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "5/13/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
df <- structure(list(n = 120559L, min = -143.53, q1 = c(`25%` = 0), 
    median = 417.524, mean = 512.838195862607, q3 = c(`75%` = 896.6585), 
    max = 23424.314), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

kable(df, format = 'simple')
```
````

[image]